# Посчитать количество повторений символов

Tags: c, строки

Нужно посчитать количество повторений символов, которые ввожу с клавиатуры, но проблема в том, что нужно использовать кодировку Windows chcp 1251. Когда ввожу букву, например, "Т", - считывается код символа и он равен -46, хотя в 1251 его код 210. Подозреваю, я неправильно понимаю, какого типа должны быть считанные данные, char или int. Подскажите:

```
#define MAX 256
char text[3000];

void main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "ukr");
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    gets_s(text);
    Probability();
    getchar();
}

void Probability(void)
{
    int* c = (int*)&text[0];
    int i;
    int m = 0; // кількість символів у файлі (без повторень)
    while (*c != 0) {
        int repeat = 0; // чи перевірявся символ
        int count = 1; // кількість повторень певного символа
        for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            if (*c == checked[i]) {
                repeat = 1; // символ уже перевірявся
                break;
            }
        }
        if (repeat == 0) {
            checked[m] = *c;
            int* comp = c + 1;
            while (*comp != 0) {
                if (*comp == *c) {
                    count++;
                    }
                }
            numbers[m] = count;
            m++;
            }
        c++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С выставленным кодом стало больше ясности

```
char text[3000];

int* c = (int*)&text[0];
```

Итак, что происходит с данным кодом:

допустим есть строка

```
text = "abcdefghijk"
```

в ней `text[0] = 'a'`, `text[1] = 'b'` и т.д.

теперь что происходит - вы говорите, что переменная `c` указывает на область в памяти, в которой хранятся `int`, т.е. 4байтовые сущности

в итоге `x[0] = 'abcd'` в виде числа, это уже не символ, это число около миллиарда

Answer (score 2):

> -46, хотя в 1251 его код 210.

открою маленький секрет - символ - это `unsigned char` - у него значение от 0 до 255

ну а когда вы используете `char` у которого значение от -128 до 127, то и получаются такие вещи

кстати

```
(signed char)-46 = (unsigned char)(256 - 46) = (unsigned char)210
```

так что просто поаккуратнее с типами,

`-46` и `210` это одно и тоже, просто одно было некорректно преобразовано

Comment: Спасибо, исправил) Но почему-то на дебаге вылезает ошибка при чтении символов строки(((

Comment: как именно это выглядит?